# Is there any etymological motivation for “I-slam”, “I-srael”, “Mu-slim” and “I-smael”?

Tags: etymology, orthography, arabic, hebrew

**Background**

Looking at old German orthographies, the long-s (ſ) spelling of the following five words (and I have not found any others so far) contradicts the spelling systematics of all other words:

> Iſrael, Iſlam, Moſlem, Iſmael, Aſbeſt

Broken down to what matters for these words, a long s would only be consistent with the spelling systematics, if it were at the beginning of a syllable. While this is the case for none of these words in their German pronunciation, I can at least explain the spelling of *Aſbeſt* to some extent: It originates from the Greek *ἄ-σβεστος* and thus the first *s* was at the beginning of a syllable or word part etymologically (the second long s is consistent anyway, since it is followed by a *t).* I now wonder whether there is a similar explanation for the other words.

**Actual Question**

Is there any etymological predecessor for any of the words *Israel, Islam, Moslem* (muslim) and *Ismael* (Ishmael), in which the *s* (or a corresponding sound) was at the beginning of a syllable <s>or word part</s>?

**Update**

Thanks to the comments and answers so far, I looked into Semitic morphology and understood that the concept of discrete word parts cannot be applied here. Still, my question about syllables stands, since they are relevant for long-s spelling, regardless of the underlying morphology.

Also, I looked for other words of Semitic origin (and with an *s* in a comparable position), and found only *Kismet* and *Esra,* both spelt without a long s.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "word part". Islam and muslim both have the same S-M-L 'peace, surrender' root; this also shows up in Hebrew _shalom_. Semitic languages have interesting word-formation procedures.

Comment: @jlawler: *Word part* can really be any meaningful division. To take *Islam* for example: Anything that justifies saying that this word is composed of *I* and *slam* or that it is pronounced *I-slam* (in contrast to *Is-lam).*

Comment: The meaningful division is the consonants and the vowels, with assorted pre- and suffixes. Look into Semitic morphology.

Comment: Might it be phonetic? "Esra" is actually written with zayin in Hebrew, hence English transliteration "Ezra" - don't know about Kismet. Probably the authors tried to indicate a voiceless "s" pronunciation (rather than an English "z" sound) by using long s in that context and an English "z" sound when using "s". To dispel/confirm, could you search the Bible for more words written originally with shin, samekh and zayin, at the beginning or the middle, and show how they're transliterated in Greek/Latin and in German?

Comment: Joe Pineda, I thought you were interested in the distribution of long s and s. Here's a good source http://babelstone.blogspot.com/2006/06/rules-for-long-s.html

Comment: @AlexB.: Note that those rules are covering languages other than German, in which the rules focussed on typographical aspects (e.g., which letter follows, and so on). The (final) German rules, however mainly focussed on other aspects.

Comment: @JoePineda: I will do so, as soon as I have access to my blackletter bibles again, which will take some time, however. On second thought this may not help that much, as the typesetters maybe as puzzled about the conventions for these cases than I am.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, what exactly do you mean by "old German orthographies?" Do you mean certain typefaces (e.g. Fraktur) or languages (e.g. Old High German)? Where did you see these spellings (dialect, time)? And, most importantly, why do you think there was no variation in their spelling?

Comment: @AlexB: I am talking about the orthographies for the 19th century and the first half of the 20th century. The long s was mainly used in, but not limited to blackletter then. The spellings I am talking about come from various dictionaries, and while there was some variation (even in the example words), I still have no idea why somebody would have the idea to spell them like that in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Islam and Muslim return to one root S-L-M س ل م which means peace and surrender as professor jlawler said. Ismael is composed of two parts which are Isma (or yishma) and El. Isma is from the Semitic root S-M-ʕ س م ع (In Hebrew the S here is Sh) which means hearing. El means God in Hebrew and in Arabic. The word Israel is composed of Isra (or yisra) and El. Isra is derived from the Semitic root Ṣ-R-ʕ ص ر ع which means contending.

Conclusion:
All of the words you asked about have roots starting with S.

Comment: Thank you so far, but could you clarify the following, please? Does whatever is before the *s* in these words carry its own meaning? And: Are or were there cases with nothing before the *s* in pronunciation, so for example, it was just *Sra-el?*

Comment: Wrong question. You're assuming that the parts are continuous; in Semitic languages they often aren't.

Comment: @jlawler: Considering meaning and morphology, I got that now. But syllables should still be continuous.

Comment: Syllables are continuous. But the meaningful parts of semitic morphology are not syllables. Syllables have almost nothing to do with semitic morphology.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft forget about syllables. In Semitic languages what matters is the consonantic root, usually 2 or 3 consonants. The root gives you the general meaning, vowels the specific one - so, depending on where the vowels go, the same triconsonantal root can give you words with one, 2, 3 or 4 syllables!! Probably that's what the original writers of the text you're seeing wanted to emphasize by using such large "s" - that such consonant was special and formed a logical group (rather than a syllable) with what followed in the word.

Comment: @JoePineda: As I said, I got the broad concept of Semitic roots and see now that the part of my question regarding word parts does not apply. Nontheless, I am interested in pronounced syllables for their own sake – see the update to my question.

Comment: The first part of ישראל cannot be derived from a root Ṣ-R-ʕ, it is traditionally derived from the root שׂ־ר־ה "to rule".

Answer (score 3):

The root of the word ‘Israel’ is sin-resh-he (ש ר ה) combined with אל (god).

The first two syllables in the names Ismael [yishma’el  -ישמעאל ] and Israel [yiśra’el - ישראל] are actually finite verb forms of the same type (yi + first stem consonant + second stem consonant + vowel + third/last stem consonant] which basically indicates: the third person singular masculine verb form [he … s: in casu ‘he hears’ and ‘he fights’].

In the case of the words muslim and islām we’re dealing with a passive participle and a noun belonging to the verb ‘aslam’ (to submit, to bring to peace) which is derived from the basic triconsonantal stem S-L-M; the word ‘muslim’ means basically ‘submitted’, and ‘islām’ means ‘submission’; the corresponding third person singular masculine verb form in Arabic from this verb is ‘yuslim’.